# ElasticTranscoder gem throws vague error when creating job

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder, aws-elastictranscoder

When trying to create a job in the AWS Transcoder pipeline, I'm getting
`Aws::ElasticTranscoder::Errors::BadRequest`. I'm pretty sure I have the params right, but I'm still getting this ambiguous error. Has anyone encountered that?

My call looks like this

```
client = Aws::ElasticTranscoder::Client.new(
      access_key_id: Rails.application.credentials.aws_s3_access_key_id,
      secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws_s3_secret_access_key,
      region: Rails.application.credentials.aws_s3_region,
      endpoint: 'https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
    )


params = {:pipeline_id=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx",
 :inputs=>
  [{:key=>"test/folder1/0.mp4", :frame_rate=>"auto", :resolution=>"auto", :aspect_ratio=>"auto", :interlaced=>"auto", :container=>"auto"},
   {:key=>"test/folder1/1.mp4", :frame_rate=>"auto", :resolution=>"auto", :aspect_ratio=>"auto", :interlaced=>"auto", :container=>"auto"}],
 :output=>{:key=>"final.mp4", :preset_id=>"1351620000001-000010"}}

client.create_job(params)
```

Pipeline is active and it's in the same region. So is s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the `endpoint` param in the client that made this mess... Just remove it. Hope this will hint someone and spare a few hours of debugging.